# deselect the alert in javascript

Tags: javascript, alert

I am working on some project and I have used alert type function in my project.
I want to do a task is that if I cross or cancel the alert box then i don't want to continue the task

```
    <td><input type="submit" Onclick="myfunction()" value="Delete">   <input type="reset" value="Reset"></td>
    <script>
function myfunction() {
    alert("You are trying to delete faculty record permanently");
}
</script>
```

In above code if i cancel the alert box then i want to return on previous page and if I click on OK on alert box then i want to perform task successfully
can anyone suggest me that how can i do this task??

Comment: You may want to use `confirm` instead of `alert`!

Answer (score 1):

`alert()` is for displaying a message. If you want to confirm something, you can use the aptly named `confirm()`:

```js
if(confirm("Should we do it?")) {
  alert("We did it!");
} else {
  alert("Or not.");
}
```

You will also probably want to attach this handler to the `onsubmit` event of the form. In fact, simply setting `onsubmit="confirm('…')"` will work; the return values match up.

Comment: ohk Thanks actually i am very new to javascript thats why i don't know about it.

Answer (score 1):

[`alert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) will just alert text (message) to the user, it doesn't expect any input or interactions.

[`confirm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) on the other hand will check if the user want to proceed or cancel by letting the user choose between two buttons.

[`prompt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) will prompt the user to enter some text and then return it so it can be used.

**Example:**

In your case you need to use `confirm` like this:

```js
var result = confirm("You want to continue?"); // confirm will return either true or false

if(result)
  alert("Let's continue then!");
else
  alert("Bye!");
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with `Window.alert()` as it returns `undefined`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert

I think what you're looking for is `Window.confirm()`. This returns a boolean depending on what button (typically "OK" or "Cancel") you clicked. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm

```js
result = confirm('You are trying to delete faculty record permanently')
if (result) {
  alert('Delete record')
} else {
  alert('Do not delete record')
}
```